# HTML/CSS shapes div layout one on top of the other

Tags: html, css, css-position

I've got this shape made:
https://jsfiddle.net/5vue1buj/1/

However, the way I'm doing this is by inserting:

```
   <br /><br /><br /><br />
```

in between the top and bottom. How do I do this more elegantly?

Comment: Absolute positioning...simple enough. Although frankly, I'd use an SVG.

Comment: Margins, padding or absolute positioning.

Comment: @Paulie_D i updated it so that both of them are position:absolute https://jsfiddle.net/5vue1buj/2/ however now i can't see one of them

Comment: Post your code in your question please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove all inline styling.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/5vue1buj/6/)**

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div id="top">
        <div class="triangle-down-right">
            <!--empty-->
        </div>
        <div class="triangle-down-left">
            <!--empty-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom">
        <div class="triangle-up-right">
            <!--empty-->
        </div>
        <div class="triangle-up-left">
            <!--empty-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then add this **CSS**:

```
#top, #bottom {
    float: none;
    overflow: hidden;    
}
#top {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By using css styles `margin/padding` you can achieve this.

In your case you have to clear the space between the two containers [top and bottom]. By default div elements are left aligned. I have added an empty `div`which will remove the space in between the two container `[using clear:both. height and overflow is added for Cross browser compatibility]`
please check this       [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5vue1buj/3/).

Answer (score 1):

#### By using  minimal of html and css

You can use only two `div` and two its psuedo elements **:after** and **:before**

```css
.bottom {
    position:absolute;
    width:210px;
    top:180px;
}
.upper {
    position:absolute;
    width:210px;
    top:20px;
}
.upper:before {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 100px solid #4679BD;
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;
}
.upper:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 100px solid #4679BD;
    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
}
.bottom:before {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 100px solid #4679BD;
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;
}
.bottom:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 100px solid #4679BD;
    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="upper"></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way, with much less CSS...

```css
#top, #bottom {
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

.right, .left {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

#top {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.left {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#top .left {
    border-top: 200px solid transparent;
    border-right: 200px solid #4679bd;
}

#top .right {
    border-top: 200px solid transparent;
    border-left: 200px solid #4679bd;
}

#bottom .left {
    border-bottom : 200px solid transparent;
    border-right: 200px solid #4679bd;
}

#bottom .right {
    border-bottom: 200px solid transparent;
    border-left: 200px solid #4679bd;
}
```

```html
<div>    
  <div id="top">
    <div class="left"></div><div class="right"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="bottom">
    <div class="left"></div><div class="right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here another example.

It uses pseudo elements and some new css3 properties to minimize the html markup down to only one div. This div is relatively positioned, but could as well be positioned absolutely for easily placing it wherever you like on the page.

A [sophisticated jsfiddle can be found here](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/por1xtop/) where you can play around if the values easily (using [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/)).

```css
#shape{
    position:relative;
    background:#4679BD;
    width:200px;height:200px;
    transform:rotate(45deg);
    margin-top:50px;margin-left:50px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#shape::before,#shape::after{
    content:"";display:block;
    position:absolute;
    width:300px;height:10px;
    background:white;
    transform:rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin:5px 5px;
    left:-5px;top:-5px;
}
#shape::after{
    transform:rotate(-45deg);
    bottom:-5px;top:auto;right:-5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="shape"></div>
```

Size is easily adjustable by adjusting the width of the pseudo elements like: (dim of shape + 5) * 1,414 and the height determines the gap between the triangles.